# Print Business card

Tags: windows, printing, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good tool to create professional looking business cards?](https://superuser.com/questions/19167/what-is-a-good-tool-to-create-professional-looking-business-cards)

I'm trying to create business card on adobe Photoshop. But I feel that, PS is not right choose for this reason: First of all after creating 1 business card, I can't duplicate it automatically to fill a4 page. I have to do it manually, one by one by duplicating 1 business card.

After googling a bit,I've found [another application](http://www.nchsoftware.com/businesscard/index.html) but it'stoo simple, no way to change standarts templates.

Which application is right for professional business card design?

Comment: It really depends on what you need. We can't help you in any other way then looking for business card software online. Polling for the "best" or "right" application is considered not constructive. Or you could ask about how to achieve what you want in Photoshop, i.e. duplicating the final business cards without manual work — that'd surely be a problem we can help you with. If you [edit] your question, I'd be happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want out of it. If you want something highly customizable and stylized, you could draft the card in Illustrator, which would allow you to array out the cards as you wish.

If you want just basic drafting of business cards, MS Word has many templates you can pull which will align the cards out for you according to whatever print medium you are using (i.e. Avery ####).